# Join by key of JSON column giving error in MySQL 5.6 but working in MySQL 8.0.19

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

My current code is,

```
$query->leftJoin('templates as t', 't.id', '=', DB::Raw("CAST(revisions.value->'$.template_id' AS UNSIGNED)"));
```

In this case value is a JSON column in revisions table.

It is perfectly working in MySQL 8.0.19 but throwing error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>"$.template_id" AS UNSIGNED) left join" in MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json support was added in [mysql v5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) only, therefore no json operators are supported in v5.6. The column path operator (->) was [added in v5.7.9](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path). You need to migrate to at least v5.7.9 for this code to work in mysql.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there any other way to work with JSON in MySQL 5.6

Comment: Only the standard string functions are available, which are not of much use for processing a complex json.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Shadow.